# The object is an Array or IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I wonder if there is a way to find if the object is an array or IEnumerable, it was more beautiful than this:

```
var arrayFoo = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };

var testArray = IsArray(arrayFoo);
// return true
var testArray2 = IsIEnumerable(arrayFoo);
// return false

var listFoo = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

var testList = IsArray(listFoo);
// return false
var testList2 = IsIEnumerable(listFoo);
// return true


private bool IsArray(object obj)
{
    Type arrayType = obj.GetType().GetElementType();
    return arrayType != null;
}

private bool IsIEnumerable(object obj)
{
    Type ienumerableType = obj.GetType().GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault();
    return ienumerableType != null;
}
```

Comment: There's a fundamental problem with this question: Arrays *are* IEnumerable.

Comment: Your `IsEnumerable` only check for a generic type. `MyAbstractClass<T>` will return true.

Comment: You `IsIEnumerable` doesn't test if an item is an `IEnumerable`.  It tests whether the type is a generic type with at lest one generic parameter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an `is` keyword in C#:

```
private bool IsArray(object obj)
{
    return obj is Array;
}

private bool IsIEnumerable(object obj)
{
    return obj is IEnumerable;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Does this help?

**"is" keyword**

Checks if an object is compatible with a given type.

```
static void Test(object value)
{
    Class1 a;
    Class2 b;

    if (value is Class1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("o is Class1");
        a = (Class1)o;
        // Do something with "a."
    } 
}
```

**"as" keyword**

Attempts to cast the value to a given type.  If cast fails, null is returned.

```
Class1 b = value as Class1;
if (b != null)
{
   // do something with b
}
```

**REFERENCE**

"is" keyword

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

"as" keyword

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)